# Cuando aplico "Match User" no inicia ssh service

Tags: linux

Al momento de que quiero enjaular un usuario ssh, y aplico en sshd_config :

```
#Jaula de usuario acceso
Match User acceso 
ChrootDirectory %h
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
X11Forwarding no
```

Reinicio el servicio de ssh y me manda

> FAIL
>   [....] Restarting ssh (via systemctl): ssh.serviceJob for ssh.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status ssh.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
>    failed!